# Having trouble including MediaFile in .NET project

Tags: c#, .net

I've never used .NET or C# before, so this might be an easy one. I'm on a mac running this project from the command line and using VScode to edit. I created an app using the command `dotnet new console -o myApp`. The error I get when I try `dotnet run` is:

> Program.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MediaFile'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?) [/Users/me/myApp/myApp.csproj]
>
> The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.

Here is my code. I'm attempting to use a library called MediaToolkit to convert a video from flv to mp4

```
using System;
using MediaToolkit; // installed using command: 'dotnet add package MediaFile'
// using MediaFile; doesn't work

namespace myApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var inputFile = new MediaFile {Filename = "/Users/me/Desktop/example.flv"};
            var outputFile = new MediaFile {Filename = "/Users/me/Desktop/example.mp4"};
            using (var engine = new Engine())
            {
                engine.Convert(inputFile, outputFile);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you [look at FuGet](https://www.fuget.org/packages/MediaToolkit), MediaToolkit package doesn't support .NET Core. Only .NET Frame 2.0 and .NET Framework 4.0. Someone [did do a port](https://www.fuget.org/packages/MediaToolkit.NetCore) which supports .NET Standard (which can be consumed by .NET Core), so perhaps you should look into that instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
 using MediaToolkit.Model;
```

try this namespace.It works in my code.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
string FilePath = @"Path-of-your-file";
```

```
#region NReco Package  
FFProbe ffProbe = new NReco.VideoInfo.FFProbe();
MediaInfo videoInfo = ffProbe.GetMediaInfo(FilePath);
double durationInTotalMinutes = videoInfo.Duration.TotalMinutes
#endregion
```

```
#region OpenCvSharp Package
VideoCapture vidCapture = new VideoCapture(FilePath);
double totalFrameCount = vidCapture.Get(VideoCaptureProperties.FrameCount);
double framesPerSeconds = vidCapture.Get(VideoCaptureProperties.Fps);
double videoDurationInSeconds = totalFrameCount / framesPerSeconds;
#endregion
```

```
#region Mediatoolkit Package
var inputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = FilePath };
using (var engine = new Engine())
{
  engine.GetMetadata(inputFile);
}
int durationInMinutes = inputFile.Metadata.Duration.Minutes;
#endregion
```

> Be sure using namespace => using MediaToolkit.Model;

**I tried installing 3 packages and the only one that worked for me was Mediatoolkit I found all the people recommended it**

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Code should be pasted as text, and formatted using Markdown. (The toolbar in the Stack Overflow editor can help you with this.) Code within images is harder to read, less accessible, can't be copied, and doesn't show up in relevant searches. Please [edit] your post to include the code as text; this will help you get better responses, and help prevent your answer from getting deleted.

Comment: Thanks for your advice